# Unwanted foreign code inserting itself into common HTML markup on removal of ashx extension from sitecore rich text editor

Tags: migration, sitecore, rich-text-editor

Our Website has been developed in sitecore in which major part has been migrated, during migration '`ashx`' was not handled well, though I have fixed the issue in `web.config` for ashx but inside `Html` editor of sitecore whenever I am trying to remove the ashx extension from relative URL's, unwanted foreign code inserting itself into common HTML markup.
For ex : if their is a image source in RTE `'src="~/media/publishingimages/chrome/twitter-24x24.ashx'` than on removal of ashx as extension it can generate some foreign code like `'<p>&amp;nbsmediaid="{926DCA21-6D10-4DF5-9C66-9156F8894F7C}" p;</p>` kindly suggest

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to remove those attributes in a consistent fashion by overriding this default pipeline: Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetFieldValue

This post provides a good example except you would want GetFieldValue not SetParametersExtended as in the example:
http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/sitecorebetter/posts/2013/06/extending-the-sitecore-renderfield-pipeline.aspx